# Linking two users in active directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have a set of users in Active Directory. They are technical users, ie not associated to a real person. I need to associate them with some password different from the one they already have. Indeed this password will give them only limited rights as compared to their full rights.

I understand that an appropriate way to do this is to create new users with similar names (for example, if I have an account *username*, I will create *restricted-username*). This way I can give the restricted rights to *restricted-username* and use this user.

But doing this I will end up with twice many users to manage. Is there a way to link two users ? For instance, if I delete *username*, then *restricted-username* is deleted as well ? Or linking properties of the two users (some properties of *restricted-username* would points to the ones of *username*)?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you’re in this position then you’ve designed your network wrong to begin with. But you haven’t asked us how to solve the problem. Instead you have asked how to implement your “solution.” So it’s hard to help.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to comment my question. I am trying to solve the following problem: give a technical account some credentials to access an API. I do not want to use the AD password of this technical account to avoid bad usages. Do you have advises on how I should do this ?

Comment: It’s still not clear what you are asking for. It would be good to [edit] your answer instead of providing more info via comments. Perhaps [“Service Accounts”](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356(v=ws.10).aspx) are what you are looking for. Or perhaps the [deny login locally](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957048.aspx) or [deny access to this computer from the network](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221954(v=ws.11).aspx) are what you are looking for.

Comment: I have reformulated my question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/883782/identifying-service-accounts as the above question was answered by Zac67.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a similar user with a different name and different privileges somehow linked to an original user. AD can't do this. A user account is a user account and privileges or group membership are granted to the user account/SID.